# How can I prevent CSS header from making drop downs disapear in Django form

Tags: python, css, django, django-forms, choicefield

Hello I am using modelforms . One of my entries is a ChoiceField, when I have my CSS header in the name.html file (the html file for the form page) the page does not show the drop downs. When I remove this header in name.html the drop downs show. Can anyone explain what is happening?

name.html

```
{% extends 'fitness/header.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

header.html

```
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <!-- Prism CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "tinymce/css/prism.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Gainz.com</a>    <!––    Need to adjust this logo           ––>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right 

      hide-on-med-and-down">


        {% if user.is_authenticated %}

          <li><a href="/profile">profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="/logout">logout</a></li>
          <li><a href="/dashboard">dashboard</a></li>
          <li><a href="/feed">feed</a></li>
          <li><a href="/forum">forum</a></li>
          <li><a href="/manual">manual entry</a></li>


        {% else %}

          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/feed">feed</a></li>
          <li><a href="/login">login</a></li>
          <li><a href="/register">register</a></li>

        {% endif %}

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  {% block content %}

  {% endblock %}


</body>




<!-- Prism JS -->
<script src="{% static "tinymce/js/prism.js" %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this to the top of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> //always include this at the top of the page of your base file
<html>
```

Scripts always go on the bottom of the page **before** the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static "tinymce/js/prism.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is generally rendered with with a `footer.html` template using `{% include 'footer.html' %}`

I added the `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` jquery script because it looks like the cloudfare materialize script requires it (although I'm not sure).  Regardless, you should be using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on all your html files! ;-)

Also, I'm not sure if this will fix your problem or not, but its generally good practice to make sure **all** of your elements have closing tags (if they require them).  There might be a random `<div>` tag on your name.html (or somewhere else) that is causing unexpected errors.